# Trying to check if document with fields exists and if so edit it in pymongo

Tags: python, pymongo

I'm trying to work a bit with pymongo, and I currently have a database that I need to look inside, and if the document with a specific field exists, then the document should be updated.

```
First I created a entry by running this a few times:
import pymongo 
client = pymongo.MongoClient()
mydb = client["mydb"]
data = {'name': "john"}
mycol = mydb['something']

mycol.insert_one(data)
```

Which works the way I want it to.

Now, I need to check whether or not  an entry exists where name = "john".

I followed [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mongodb-check-the-existence-of-the-fields-in-the-specified-collection/) tutorial, which basically just shows this snippet:

```
db.student.find({name:{$exists:true}})
```

I tried to implement this, so it now looks like this:

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import cursor 
client = pymongo.MongoClient()
mydb = client["mydb"]

print(mydb.something.find({"name":{"john"}}))
```

and this just returns `<pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x7fbf266239a0>`
which I don't really know what to do with.

I also looked at some similar questions here, and found some suggestions for something like this:

```
print(mydb.values.find({"name" : "john"}).limit(1).explain())
```

But this just gives me a long json-looking string, which by the way doesnt change if I put other things in for "john".

So how do I check whether a document where "name" = "john" exists? and perhaps also then edit the document?

**EDIT**

I now tried the following solution:

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import cursor 
client = pymongo.MongoClient()
mydb = client["mydb"]
mycol = mydb['something']
name = "john"
print(mycol.find_one({name:{"$exists":True}}))
```

But it only prints me None

Answer (score 0):

Change `find()` to `find_one()`, or if you're expecting more than one result, iterate the cursor using a for loop:

```
print(db.student.find_one({'name':{'$exists': True}}))
```

or

```
for student in db.student.find({'name': {'$exists': True}}):
    print(student)
```

Comment: I have seen this example a few places, but it makes very little sense to me. What is `$exist` and `true`. my IDE has no idea

Comment: Sorry - my bad - I hadn't checked my answer; pymongo requires keys in quotes and booleans in capitals. I've edited my answer to correct.